# Copying (remotely) certain folders

Tags: bash

Assuming a directory tree:

```
dir1\
    folder1\
    folder2\
dir2
    folder1\
    folder2\
...
```

How can I copy (possibly remotely) all the folder2 directories, preserving the tree structure. That is what I want to get in another location is

```
dir1\
    folder2\
dir2
    folder2\
...
```

I tried to do some combinations of `find` and `cp` (or `scp`/`rsync`) but could not put it together properly.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `rsync` command. Something like this would do the trick.

```
rsync -av --include='dir*' --include='folder2**' --exclude='*'  . new
```

First use the `include` option for matching the interested directories and then `exclude` in order to not process the rest of the files. Finally, we copy all the tree directory, the `folder2` of each one and its content by using double asterisk.

Example of output:

```
root@FS:~/test# ll
 dir1/
 dir2/
 neww/
 nn]/
root@FS:~/test# rsync -av --include='dir*' --include='folder2**' --exclude='*'  . new
sending incremental file list
created directory new
dir1/folder2/
dir1/folder2/test1
dir1/folder2/test2
dir2/folder2/

sent 170 bytes  received 61 bytes  462.00 bytes/sec
total size is 0  speedup is 0.00
```

As you can see, only `dir1/folder2/` and `dir2/folder2/` are copied.

Finally, you can use `rsync` by specifying the destination folder as remote.

```
rsync -av source_directory username@remote_host:destination_directory
```

For further information, here the [manpage](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/trusty/en/man1/rsync.1.html).

Comment: Just a comment that, this in itself would not copy the contents of the directories. We'd need another `--include` with names of the files.

Comment: You are completely right. I have edit the answer with possible fix. Using `**` we can match anything, including slashes. So all files and folders inside `folder2` will be copied.